# Finding Current Page in SailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

Does anyone know of a prettier way to output a class name to a list element (in this case) using EJS?

```
 <% var active = "active"; %>
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li class="<% if(req.path == '/user') { %><%= active %><% } %>"><a href="/user">Users</a></li>
      <li class="<% if(req.path == '/about') { %><%= active %><% } %>"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="<% if(req.path == '/contact') { %><%= active %><% } %>"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">Sails Tutorial App</h3>
  </div></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :)

```
<li class="<%= (req.path == '/user') ? 'active' : '' %>"><a href="/user">Users</a></li>
```

It's a little bit prettier I guess...